# How to make the QT creator built application always use light mode theme on macOS Mojave?

Tags: qt, macos-mojave

I have a QT creator built application which appears fine on macOS Mojave while the system uses the light theme but it looks worse when change to dark theme.

Could I made the application to keep the light theme no matter what the system theme is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to exclude an app from dark mode (please have a look here at https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/exclude-app-dark-mode-macos-mojave/.

However, it may not work since the issue you are facing ***may*** be with Qt itself. Applications built with an SDK prior to 10.14 will run with a mixed dark/light palette on Mojave. To solve the issue you must build your app with SDK 10.14 (more info about that [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68850) and [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/41206326).

This happened to me with one app: my build machine was running High Sierra (thus using SDK 10.13) and when I ran the application on Mojave with the dark theme I got very wierd results. Once I upgraded my build machine to Mojave, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I have Xcode 10.1 with macOS SDK 10.14 install on my Mojave 10.14. The QT creator version is 5.9.7. What else do I need?

Comment: Qt 5.9 does not support SDK 10.14 (as per documentation), nor the dark mode. Upgrade to Qt 5.12. More info [here](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/11/08/qt-macos-10-14-mojave/)